# "RNGCryptoServiceProvider does not contain a definition for GetNonZeroBytes"

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, compiler-errors

I have the following code. The function is to generate a random ID of a specific size. However i keep getting an error that says

> 'System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider' does not contain a definition for 'GetNonZeroBytes' and no extension method 'GetNonZeroBytes' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference)

I am trying to use the cryptography library in .NET and according to msdn this is one of the functions that can be used in this scenario but for some reason i keep getting this error.

Can anyone help?

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Ink;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

namespace ONeRESPONSEAPP
{
    public class IdGenerator
    {
        public static string GetUniqueKey(int maxSize)
        {
            char[] chars = new char[45];
            chars =
            "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890".ToCharArray();
            byte[] data = new byte[1];
            RNGCryptoServiceProvider identity= new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
            identity.GetNonZeroBytes(data);
            data = new byte[maxSize];
            identity.GetNonZeroBytes(data);
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(maxSize);
            foreach (byte b in data)
            {
                result.Append(chars[b % (chars.Length)]);
            }
            return result.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Something wrong is with your .NET, I'm able to compile this code well. What environment are you using?

Comment: I tried it in .NET 3.5, 4.0 and 4.5 (both full and client profile), works perfectly fine.

Comment: @OrvillePatterson: What .Net profile are you targetting?

Comment: The only think I can think of is that there is a `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` in the local namespace. Try: `new System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider()`

Comment: its a WP7 app. Im working on the registration module so i'm using this function to generate a random ID.

Comment: @caesay Although, as far as I can tell, it's been supported on everything since .NET 1.1

Comment: @OrvillePatterson With the *same* error? (Then, no idea.)

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider.GetNonZeroBytes()` is [*not* supported by Windows Phone 7](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).
You might want to use [`RNGCryptoServiceProvider.GetBytes()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider.getbytes%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) instead, it is cryptographic strong as well.